# Delete empty folder Linux

Tags: linux, shell

To remove all files & subdirectories from a directory, use the below given command.

```
$ rm -rf directoryname
```

I'm looking to delete an empty directory. I tried by `rm -rf -empty /folder/folder1/Folder2`

but doesn't work ? How can I do it ?

Comment: `rmdir /folder/folder_to_delete`?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, I edited my question

Comment: `rm -rf` will delete an empty directory (as well as a non-empty).

Answer (score 1):

The traditional solution is `rmdir`:

```
rmdir /folder/folder_to_delete
```

It will fail if the directory is not empty.

Comment: I edited my question